# VlnPlot pvalue addition

Tags: p-value, violin-plot, seurat

For some reason I can't seem to be getting the p-values, I just get my plot back as it is and the following warning message:

```
Warning messages: 
1: Removed 22217 rows containing non-finite outside the scale range (`stat_ydensity()`). 
2: Removed 22217 rows containing non-finite outside the scale range (`stat_signif()`). 
3: Computation failed in `stat_signif()`. Caused by error in `wilcox.test.default()`: ! not enough 'y' observations 
4: Removed 22217 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range (`geom_point()`).
```

[image: VlnPlot image]

Here is my code:

```
VlnPlot(object = S, features = "Hif1a", split.by = "GT") +
stat_compare_means(comparisons = S$sub_cluster) +
ylim(0, 5)

#GT (KO+WT); sub_cluster (assigned clusters)
```

Comment: What package does `stat_compare_means()` come from, and what does `S$sub_cluster`contain?

Comment: stat_compare_means() comes from ggpubr, and S$sub_cluster contained my assigned/annotated clusters

Comment: Would this be of help? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78148672/p-value-is-not-calculated-and-shown-in-ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78148672/p-value-is-not-calculated-and-shown-in-ggplot)